# How to enable Media Services App Developer Account to Create a Key for it?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to create a Media Services Key in developer.apple.com. The issue is it's grayed out. Does anyone know why? It says

> There are no identifiers available that can be associated with the key

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the [Create a private key to access a service](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-keys/create-a-private-key) procedure, in which step 4 says "If the Media Services checkbox is disabled, you need to register a media identifier first."

That step links to the [Register a media identifier](https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/create-a-media-identifier-and-private-key#register-a-media-identifier) procedure, which instructs how to create an identifier in the developer account section titled Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. Here it is:

**Register a media identifier**

1. In [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources), click Identifiers in the sidebar.
2. On the top left, click the add button (+), select Media IDs, then click Continue.
3. Enter the app name as the description.

- The app name is displayed to users when requesting access to Apple Music.

4. Enter a reverse-domain name style string for the identifier, then click Continue.
5. Review the information, then click Register.
6. Click Done.